# No connection as non root using Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: linux, perl, sftp

I am trying to use a perl script to transfer files from one machine to another within a cron job. However for security reasons the cron job has to run as a unprivileged user. Now if I try to establish a connection using this unpriviliged user, `Net::SFTP::Foreign` always refuses to connect. Here is the part of the script I am having trouble with:

```
my $host = "hostname";
my %args = (
    user => "username",
    password => "password",                                                                                                                                                                                       
    port => '12345'
);
my $sftp_connection = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, %args);
if( $sftp_connection->error ) {
    log_message( "E", "Error " . $sftp_connection->status() . " connecting to " . $host );
    die;
}
log_message( "A", "Connected" );
```

I cannot give a full example, as this would require username and password.

If I execute this script as root, everything works fine, however if I try to use another user, the connection always fails.

Is there a way to get some more diagnostic information? I think there was a way to get more output from the actual sftp process, but I cannot look it up right now as cpan currently does not work from here.

I previously also tried using `Net::SFTP` instead of `Net::SFTP`, but the error handling at later parts did not work correctly, so switching to `Net::SFTP` does not seem a viable option right now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, is there any important thing missing in this example? Have you tried to make the connection using the ssh/sftp command from the non-privilege account?

Comment: Enable debugging: `$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug = -1;`

Comment: @Salva: Thank you for the hint with the debugging, I could not look it up because CPAN was unreachable.

Comment: You don't need access to a CPAN web front-end in order to read the documentation for installed modules. Just use `perldoc` from a terminal. On most Linux distributions, module docs are also installed as manpages: `man Net::SFTP::Foreign`.

Comment: @Salva: Thanks for the hint. I almost never use Perl, so I'll try to remember that for the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling debugging (thanks to all commenters), I could see that the host-key verification failed. So after I added the key to the list of allowed keys (by doing a manual ssh to the host once), everything worked fine.

For root the key must have been in the list already, so that it had nothing to do with priviledge, just with prior usage of the account (I seem have ssh'ed before from root to the other host).

Answer (score 1):

1. Use metacpan.org
2. Debugging:

For debugging purposes you can run ssh in verbose mode passing it the -v option:
`my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, more => '-v');`

["Module description"](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. This response is more of a "comment" than an "answer". If the OP does reply with the output from debugging attemps you can edit your response to provide a full answer.

Comment: Hi. I wanted to add comment, but got an error of lack of reputation :(.